# Create an api for existing web application in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have 2 separate projects:

1. Web API
2. Web application (GUI)

Both will have the same logic and code, it's just their return type that are different.

Obviously the API will return json, and the web app will have views.

My question: is there a way to use the same controllers and actions for both web app and api? I just don't want to [repeat myself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and use less code.

What I have found is that you can have multiple routes for your controller, and then you can get the current url in your controller.

So something like:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("[controller]")]
class MyController:ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Hi()
    {
     // if (url startwith "api")
     //return json
     //otherwise return some view
    }

}
```

I didn't try myself because I wasn't sure if this was a right way to solve it or not, and on the other hand I have to put that if check in all the methods...

Comment: `ControllerBase` is for API only - it lacks support for views. So if you want to write just one code base to be used as both an API and a web app, you need to descend from `Controller` instead

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your tip, is that all i need to do? so how can i make it work with both api and web app? with those if checks?

Comment: One way would be to have separate method calls for API and web - and just not have barely any code in the controller method itself, but put that real logic code into separate classes which can be called from both the API controller method, as well as the web app controller method.

Comment: @marc_s yes that was the first thing i thought , but there is a problem with that, that logic need so many different dependencies, that currently resolving by Ioc container, if i separate the logic from controller i should manually resolve those dependencies....

Comment: I think you can try the method you mentioned. I think that all you need is declare a controller action. Like this: [connecting web api aspnet core mvc application](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/connecting-web-api-aspnet-core-mvc-application).

Comment: @AliSalehi No, just because you move that logic out of the controller doesn't mean that you have to throw away Dependency Injection. Move that logic into one or more classes, have those classes receive their dependencies via constructor injection (in the same way your controllers would) and then just register those new classes with the DI container, and have your controller depend on the classes via constructor injection. Dependency Injection is NOT limited to just controllers.

Comment: @mason you are right, After thinking for a while , I understood this. thank you sir.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have two different projects so you have to use different controllers and actions. You cannot use same physical controllers and actions from two different projects.

Comment: i can merge them into one project,thats not the problem